# Creation of audit via powershell fails with "SetParent Failed"

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, audit

I'm trying to create a new server audit on a WinServer 2008 R2 with the following PowerShell Script.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null 
$server = "SM1111" #change to desired instance
$instance = "S111"
$auditName = "$instance"+"TestAudit"
$auditDir = 'F:\Microsoft SQL Server\'+$instance+'AuditTestLogsNew\'
$srv = new-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') -argumentlist $instance

$newAudit = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Audit($srv, "$auditName")
$newAudit.DestinationType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AuditDestinationType]::File
$newAudit.FilePath = $auditDir
$newAudit.MaximumRolloverFiles = 10
$newAudit.MaximumFileSize = 100
$newAudit.QueueDelay = 1000
$newAudit.Create()
$newAudit.Enable()
```

However the following line always fails:

```
$newAudit = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Audit($srv, "$auditName")
```

I get the following error message:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "SetParent failed for Audit 'S111TestAudit'. "
At MYFOLDER\Documents\Auditing_Test\CreateAudit.ps1:9 char:13
+ $newAudit = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Audit($srv, "$auditNam ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I've been googling a lot, but still haven't found anything that might solve the problem, since I don't quite understand what raises the error to begin with.

I have full administrator privileges.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the server name for your instance. Your variable `$srv` is not pointing to an actual server instance.

```
$server = "SM1111" #change to desired instance     <- This isn't doing anything
$instance = "S111"
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -argumentlist "$server\$instance"
```